# Nginx more_set_input_headers throwing an error

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-16.04

i am running Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS. i am trying to upgrade my Nginix from nginx/1.10.3 to nginx/1.21.0.

when i run the upgrade and test the configuration file i get the below error

```
root@myserver:/home/myuser# nginx -t 
nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "more_set_input_headers" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/exchangeRP.conf:31 
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

This is whats i have in the conf file

```
more_set_input_headers 'Authorization: $http_authorization';
```

this option is working in v1.10.3 but not in 1.21.0 .

is there anything im missing?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 has reached it's end of life and does not receive any updates anymore. You should upgrade to a newer version, that way you'll also receiver the newer nginx versions.

Comment: Questions should demonstrate reasonable information technology management practices. Questions that relate to unsupported hardware or software platforms or unmaintained environments may not be suitable for Server Fault.

Answer (score 1):

You will need this external module: https://github.com/openresty/headers-more-nginx-module#readme

If you are compiling from source - https://github.com/openresty/headers-more-nginx-module#installation

If you are using distro packages -- they typically come in flavours e.g. minimal, full etc. Please check if you are installing the correct one.

Comment: ive checked the 1st link and i can see in the compatibility list that the last version thats its compatible with is 1.17.x . how ever i am currently running 1.21.0 . So i guess it will not be compatible?